# Remove Protection from Range

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-protection

I have created 50 spreadsheets for 50 students. Each spreadsheet contains 33 sheets, numbered 1 to 33, along with a couple of other sheets.  Within each of these 33 sheets, there are many protected ranges.  I accidentally protected a range that ought not to have been protected. So, with 50 students each having 33 sheets, I have over 1800 sheets to unprotected.

I want to loop through each sheet, 1 to 33, and remove protection from cell F15. Right now, I (the owner) am the only editor.  Since I'm not an actual programmer, I've clearly not done this properly.  Can someone offer a suggestion of how I can change my Google Script to make this work?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets(); 
for (var i=2; i  <sheets.length; i++) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[i];
  sheet.activate();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var range = sheet.getRange('F15');
       var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Protected range');
       var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
       protection.addEditor(me);
       protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
       if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
         protection.remove();
         } //end of if statement

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function start() {
  var idFolder = '0B79ClRnKS87QcW9XbVhrcFZxd28'; // change
  var sheetNames = ['1', '2', '3']; // change
  var strRange = 'A1'; // change

  deleteProtection(idFolder, sheetNames, strRange) 

}


function deleteProtection(idFolder, sheetNames, strRange) {

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(idFolder);
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var file;
  var sheet;
  var sheets;
  var sheetName;
  var range;
  var strRangeProtect;
  var protections;
  var protection;

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;

  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = app.openById(contents.next().getId());
    sheets = file.getSheets();

    for(var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      sheet = sheets[i];
      sheetName = sheet.getName();
      protections = file.getProtections(app.ProtectionType.RANGE);

      for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
        var protection = protections[i];
        var range = protection.getRange();
        var sheetName = range.getSheet().getName();
        strRangeProtect = range.getA1Notation();
        if (strRangeProtect == strRange && sheetNames.indexOf(sheetName) > 0) {
          protection.remove();
        }      
      }           
    }  
  }  
}
```

---

**Befor you start:**

First you need to paste all the files into one folder, then copy it's id:

[image]

and change this lines:

```
  var idFolder = '0B79ClRnKS87QcW9XbVhrcFZxd28'; // change
  var sheetNames = ['1', '2', '3']; // change
  var strRange = 'A1'; // change
```

Comment: How might I adjust this so I can unprotect an entire sheet?